# Is it possible to extra authentication in rdp connection

Tags: azure, server, virtual-machine

I am new to Azure. I have created a Virtual Machine windows server 2016 in Azure. When I connect it a rdp file wil download so that I can do remote desktop to  my server in Azure. This is a normal rdp connection with authentication of username and password for the machine. 
My question is , Is it possible to add an extra authentication , which is similar to Remote desktop gateway in server 2012 on-premise , in Azure server 2016. 
Could anyone help me in this, Is there any documentation ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need add `Remote desktop gateway`. On Azure, you could connect your VM by using Public IP. Also, if you want to use gateway, you could refer to this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/applicationproxyblog/2015/10/14/publishing-remote-desktop-with-azure-active-directory-application-proxy/)

Comment: I need to impose an extra security before client login to my azure VM . So what can I do for this .

Comment: Could you limit your client IP address?

Comment: Also, you could use MFA. This [link](http://www.deployazure.com/security/identity/azure-multi-factor-authentication-server-with-remote-desktop-gateway-part-1/) is step by step to configure it.

Comment: Hi Walter..The answer was useful for me ..but you just deleted ?

Comment: No, I don't know why this is delete by others.

Comment: You could not use certificate on Azure MFA.  You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-how-it-works#methods-available-for-two-step-verification).

Comment: Hi this [link](http://www.deployazure.com/security/identity/azure-multi-factor-authentication-server-with-remote-desktop-gateway-part-1/) is in my answer. Maybe you could check. Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much ...helps a lot ..

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can add further authentication for your RDP. Here is link.

[Azure Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-server-rdg)

Comment: I have seen the link .. but no step -by step procedure for  configuring rdp gateway .

Comment: hi ..Actually my doubt is  ... I have a virtual machine of server 2016 in Azure. Should I configure RDP gateway , NPS and multifactor authentication in separate machines ? or should i configure RDP gateway in the same 2016 machine .  I have configured RDP gateway in the same machine, closed the session  and tried to do rdp to that machine from azure again . But I haven't got the extra authentication window .